# How to kill a process which is started by child thread?

Tags: java, scope

Code:

```
main function{

Thread t =new Thread(){
     public void run(){
         Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(my_CMD);
     }
};
t.start();
 //Now here, I want to kill(or destroy) the process p.
```

How can I do this in Java? If I make it as a class field as in

```
main function{
Process p;
Thread t =new Thread(){
     public void run(){
         p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(my_CMD);
     }
};
t.start();
 //Now here, I want to kill(or destroy) the process p.
```

Since it is in a thread, it asks me to make the Process P as `final`. If I make that `final`, I cant assign value here. `p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(my_CMD);` . plz help.

Comment: see edit to answer. Again, your p variable is local to the method. Don't do that -- make it a class field.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for pointing that out. Was just assumining it be a class field. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Process API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) already has a solution for this. What happened when you tried calling `destroy()` on the process? Of course assuming that you've changed the above code and have declared your Process variable, p, as a class field.

As an aside, you should avoid using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` to get your Process but rather should use a ProcessBuilder. Also, don't extend Thread when Runnable can be implemented.

```
class Foo {
  private Process p;

  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(...);  // fill in ...!
      // swallow or use the process's Streams!
      p = pBuilder.start();
    }
  }

  public Foo() {
    new Thread(runnable).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: He has defined Process variable inside `run()`- it is not available outside after `t.start()` to call destroy() on it.

Comment: @BimaleshJha: I have edited my answer synchronously with your comment. It's simply a matter of scope, but hopefully if he's calling outside code this way, he understands scoping rules, otherwise he may be putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: At higher scope, I think, Process variable p must be declared final?

Comment: @BimaleshJha: yes, since it is being used in an anonymous inner class. Either that or declare it as a class field. But again, this is nothing more than basic Java.

Comment: What puzzles me about the original question is why didn't the original poster look at the API first before coming here? The answer is readily obtainable from this resource in fractions of a second.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  How can you resolve this issue with that API? I cant call p.destroy as it is out of scope. And if I make it final in mainthread, then I cant call it inside(since it is final). Am I missing something?

Comment: @shrigurunayak: yes you're missing something. Make it a class field.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did not get it still. A code snippet would help.

Comment: @shrigurunayak: what are you confused on? Again, make the Process variable p, a class field, and then you can call destroy on it anywhere in the class (assuming you first check for null). Please edit your question, and show *specifically* what has you stumped.

Comment: "What puzzles me about the original question is why didn't the original poster look at the API first before coming here?" <-- if OPs did, the number of questions pertaining to Java would be halved ;) Java may have its downsides, but documentation is certainly not one of them